# Inconsistent accessbility Error in Processcmdkey

Tags: c#, .net, windows

I am using the below mentioned code to capture the pressed key. I used it before in other solution and it's working fine there. But now it's showing error

> Inconsistent accessibility: parameter type 'ref Stock.Message' is
>   less accessible than method 'Stock.Sales.ProcessCmdKey(ref
>   Stock.Message, System.Windows.Forms.Keys)'

```
protected override bool ProcessCmdKey(ref Message msg, Keys keyData)        
    {

     try

            {
                bool handled = false;

                if (keyData == Keys.Escape)//Text box reset on ESC key press
                {
                    Some Code();
                    return true;
                }
                //Data grid row focus move up and down with Up & DOWN key press
                return (handled || base.ProcessCmdKey(ref msg, keyData));
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                throw;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

It looks like a visibility problem. Your method `ProcessCmdKey` is `Protected`, while your class `Message` is likely declared at a level below that.

You need to use the same visibility or higher with the method/item which is being used by the other one, in this case, your class `Message` needs to have the same visibility level than your function.

You can fix it in both ways, changing the method visibility, or the class `Message`.

Answer (score 0):

Review that Message class is Internal or Public. The owner class of ProcessCmdKey should have the same 'visibility'